# Cosmology and Fluid Dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, cosmology

What will be the relation between the barotropic index (w) of fluid and the velocity (v) of the fluid ???  and please mention some citation or book.

Comment: The barotropic index is related to the pressure and density of a fluid. You will need to find how the velocity affects this, possibly using a four vector velocity since you flagged it as a cosmology problem.

Comment: if you refer me a book or work, it will be very helpful to me, because I am somehow unable to understand how the velocity affects this including four-vector velocity. Thank you so much @Mick.